# YDN DB "In"-statement

Tags: ydn-db

I want to fetch all records from my database where the id is 20, 21, 22.

In sql you could say: `Select * from moo where id in (20,21,22)`

How can I do this in `ydn db`?

Unfortunately I found no working example for this issue.

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YDN-DB is yet to implement multi-query. Currently you have to query one by one.

Comment: Ah okay thank you! Do you know a indexeddb wrapper which is able to do this job?